# C#: Count Number of Digits in a String Using Do While Loop

Tags: c#

Hi I would appreciate if you could help me to fix this code. I am required to use Do While Loop.
I am receiving "Outside Bound" error.
I believe I need to substract or add 1 somewhere but can't figure out exactly where.

```
public static int Digit(string str)
        {
            if (str is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str));
            }

            int count = 0;
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(str[i]))
                {
                    count++;
                }

                i++;
            }
            while (i < str.Length);

            return count;
        }
```

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: This is happening because you're not checking whether the string is long enough to contain a character at index ```i``` before ```char.IsDigit(str[i])```.

Comment: @user9938 No that should be fine since it's incrementing `i` before checking the `while` condition. It _would_ fail for an empty string, though (`length==0`). But you could easily check for that before the `do` loop, or within the `do` loop before you get the character.

Comment: If you can use `str.Length`, what's the sense of using a loop to calculate the value of `str.Length`???

Comment: I just tested, everytning is fine , except validation.

Comment: @Dominique they said it's "required" to use do/while so I'm assuming it's an assignment.

Comment: @Dominique
I am required to use Do while loop in this exercise. do you know any other way to accomplish same thing without using str.Length but use Do while loop? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `do .. while` executes *at least once*, you have a *special case* for an *empty string*:

```
public static int Digit(string str)
{
    if (str is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str));
    
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return 0;

    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(str[i++])) // Let's make it compact
            count++;
    }
    while (i < str.Length);

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much Mr. Dmitry
You code fixed the issue.
In addition, I learned how to make the code a bit compact. 
Truly appreciate your and other responders' time.

Answer (score 1):

you have to fix validation, you exception was when string was empty, but not null

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str));
```

Comment: I believe this will also fix the issue. 
Anyway now I understand what the problem was.
Thank you